# Alternative to sscanf that makes both Linux and Windows happy

Tags: c++, visual-studio, security, gcc

I have a truly ancient [punch-card format](https://celestrak.org/NORAD/documentation/tle-fmt.php) and a C++ code that reads it using `sscanf` as follows,

```
   sscanf(longstr1,"%2d %5ld %1c %10s %2d %12lf %11lf %7lf %2d %7lf %2d %2d %6ld ",
                   &cardnumb,&satrec.satnum,&classification, intldesg, &satrec.epochyr,
                   &satrec.epochdays,&satrec.ndot, &satrec.nddot, &nexp, &satrec.bstar,
                   &ibexp, &numb, &elnum );
```

Here the first two characters of the string `longstr1` comprise an `int` read into `cardnum`, the next five comprise an `int` read into `satrec.satnum`, and so on.  (Those of a certain age will recognize this as a Hollerith format.)  The placement of the characters within the string `longstr1` never varies.

This works fine, but I have to make it work with both `gcc` on Linux and Visual Studio C++ (2017) on Windows.  VS complains that `sscanf` is insecure (I suppose it is), and recommends replacing it with `sscanf_s`, a Microsoft-only function.  I need a substitute that makes VS happy, but compiles with `gcc` on Linux, too.

Is there some secure, and perhaps easy, way to accomplish this?

Comment: Sure. It's a C++ code, not C.

Comment: @RodneyPrice `sscanf_s` is in C11, but not in C99, and never in C++.

Comment: Do you know how to use the formatted extraction operator, the `<<` operator?

Comment: No.  I'm a C++ newbie.  It's been all C for me until now.

Comment: @RodneyPrice Honestly, VS C++ is not 100% purely standard C++...

Comment: `sscanf` has no protections should you specify a buffer that it too small. It's faster because of the lack of checking, but...

Comment: Any reason not to ignore or disable the warning and continue using `sscanf`?  The potential issue is that `"%10s"` might be longer than the corresponding buffer, but if you know it's not you're ok.  If you're feeling paranoid and want to make sure the `sscanf` code automatically adjusts if a programmer ever changes the buffer size, change the format to `"%*s"` and pass in `..., sizeof intldesg - 1, intldesg, ...`.  Alternatively, `#ifdef _MSC_VER` `sscanf_s(...);` `#else` `sscanf(...);` `#endif`

Comment: An alternative might be to isolate such function calls in a separate file with the appropiate c-extension and instruct the cpp compiler to compile it as c source

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a warning but an error according to VS.  There's probably a checkbox buried deep within the bowels of VS that changes this to a warning, but I don't have time to find it.  I almost always use emacs and gcc to develop C code and I don't really want to spend the time to learn VS when this is a one-off.  Learning C++, however, is another story.  I'm happy to spend time on that.

Comment: you can disable and (re-)enable Safety Depracations with the macros _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE and _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. You could reseach those. (vcruntime.h)

Comment: Since this is being used in C++, why use `sscanf()` at all and not C++ style stream I/O instead?

Answer (score 2):

If you define `_CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_STANDARD_NAMES` on windows it will use sscanf_s whenever you write sscanf. This means that on Linux the code remains working as is, on Windows the function is automatically replaced for you with the secure version but no longer generates any warnings so both platforms should be happy. See [secure template overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/secure-template-overloads?view=vs-2019) on the microsoft docs website for more information.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Anyone who did downvote or can understand why, please elaborate. I suspect this can't work (`sscanf_s` needs different arguments)?

Comment: `sscanf_s` should work fine for most cases as there is a templated overload for string literals. I guess there may be some places where it still doesn't work although I've not yet encountered any when using that define.